# Trouble $watching model being passed to parent directive through directive attribute

Tags: angularjs

While answering a different question, I realized I was unable to pass child models to a parent directive via its attribute.

Given this setup:

```
<form child-watch mod="inputModel" name="form"><!--ignore creepy directive name-->
  <input type="text" name="one" ng-model="inputModel.one">
  <input type="text" name="two" ng-model="inputModel.two"><br/>
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$pristine">
  <p>Original Model: {{original}}</p>
  <p>Isolate Scope Model: {{isolate}}</p>
</form>
```

How can I `$watch` the inputModel within the directive via its attribute, and view the changes made by the children?  If I use isolate scope, it will only $watch UP to the parent model, which is now unaffected by the isolated children.

Obviously this doesn't work, but you can see the direction I'm going:

```
app.directive('childWatch', function(){
    return {
        // removing the isolate scope allows parent scope.inputModel to update
        scope:{
            mod: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){


            //this does not reflect change upon the parent scope.inputModel
            //if using isolate scope.  AND, I don't want to $watch a specific
            // model, because the directive needs to be reusable.  It needs to watch
            // an attribute that references the model.
            scope.$watch('inputModel', function(val){
                scope.original = val;        
            },true)


            //this only has access to the parent scope.inputModel
            scope.$watch('mod', function(i){
                scope.attribute = i;            
            }, true)
        }    
    }
})
```

In order to make the directive reusable for different models, I can't just watch a specific model.  It needs to watch an attribute that references the model.  I'm not sure this is possible.  Any ideas?

[Here's the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/sKUDU27ErGaOuJMg571i?p=preview) I'm messing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an isolate scope, only those properties referenced in `scope: { ... }` are available to the view and the directive.  Use `mod` everywhere and it will work:

```
<form child-watch mod="inputModel" name="form">
  <input type="text" name="one" ng-model="mod.one">
  <input type="text" name="two" ng-model="mod.two"><br/>
  <p>Model in attribute: {{attribute}}</p>
  <p>Original model: {{mod}}</p>
</form>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bnVaharAwlT8UoeRxAjM?p=preview)

Comment: Heh. I reasoned myself out of doing that, thinking with multiple forms/directives on the page they can't share the same model.  BUT the isolate scope makes this work.  Thank you.

Comment: Before I check - lemme ask - is there any way to accomplish this without isolate scope? To just watch the $eval'd attribute itself?

Comment: @rGil, yes, you can use $parse -- see stackoverflow.com/a/15725402/215945

Comment: That is actually the answer I was looking for.  The part I was missing was `(scope)` after `$parse(attr.whatever)`.  [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dqX1R0d4H0QBfETGzyCU?p=preview)

Comment: Interesting that you can $watch an object that is $parsed, but not one that is $eval'd.